# How to efficiently unpivot MULTIPLE columns in Hive?

Tags: hive, query-optimization, hiveql, unpivot

My data is structured like in the below table:

```
| Name | Foo_A | Foo_B | Foo_C | Bar_A | Bar_B | Bar_C |
--------------------------------------------------------
| abcd |    16 |    32 |    14 |    52 |    41 |    17 |
| ...  |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |   ... |
```

I am looking to query the data in Hive in a way such that it looks like this:

```
| Name | Class | FooVal | BarVal |
----------------------------------
| abcd | A     |     16 |     52 |
| abcd | B     |     32 |     41 |
| abcd | C     |     14 |     17 |
| ...  | ...   |    ... |    ... |
```

I am already aware of and am using a UNION ALL, but what would be a more efficient way of doing this using "LATERAL VIEW explode" a map data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reply! Please find below another way of doing it which is faster than CROSS JOIN.

```
    select t1.ID, t2.key_1 as class, t2.FooVal, t3.BarVal
    from table t1
    LATERAL VIEW explode (map(
   'A', Foo_A,
   'B', Foo_B,
   'C', Foo_C
    )) t2 as key_1, FooVal
    LATERAL VIEW explode (map(
    'A', Bar_A,
    'B', Bar_B,
    'C', Bar_C
     )) t3 as key_2, BarVal
     where t2.key_1 = t3.key_2;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this solution is not faster. Because cross join normally will execute as map-join. And your query does the same twice, multiplying rows x9, after that you filtering rows.

Answer (score 1):

CROSS JOIN with `class` `stack` (see code example) will multiply main table rows x3, one row per `class`, then use `case` statements to derive your columns depending on `class` value. CROSS JOIN with small dataset (3 rows) should be transformed to **map join** and will execute very fast on mappers.

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=true; --this enables map-join

select t.Name,
       s.class,
       case s.class when 'A' then t.Foo_A 
                    when 'B' then t.foo_B
                    when 'C' then t.foo_C
        end as FooVal,
       case s.class when 'A' then t.Bar_A 
                    when 'B' then t.Bar_B
                    when 'C' then t.Bar_C
        end as BarVal              
 from table t 
      cross join (select stack(3,'A','B','C') as class) s
;
```

It will scan the table only once and perform much better than UNION ALL approach.

Answer (score 0):

Hive unpivot multiple columns:

```
select
        t1.ID,
        lv.key         as class,
        lv.FooStr.col1 as FooVal,
        lv.FooStr.col2 as BarVal
    from
        table t1
        LATERAL VIEW explode (
            map(
               'A', named_struct('col1', Foo_A, 'col2', Bar_A),
               'B', named_struct('col1', Foo_B, 'col2', Bar_B),
               'C', named_struct('col1', Foo_C, 'col2', Bar_C)
                )) lv as key, FooStr
    where
        coalesce(lv.FooStr.col1, lv.FooStr.col2) IS NOT NULL
```